# codeigniter / mvc frameworks for browsergame

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks

I'm coding a bowsergame at the moment and wanted to do it all by myself, mostly to learn/train my php/mysql skills and for fun. I dont have any skills with neither mvc frameworks nor codeigniter. I'v seen some vids and tutorials about codeigniter and it seems to be very productive to create code faster and saver.

The Question is if codeigniter (or MCV-based frameworks over all) is helpful for coding a browsergame, since i would need some time to get into the framework and it also seems to be kinda tricky to implement your own classes and so on.

Comment: It depends on what you need for you game. For most default setups, any popular MVC framework will offer the features and structure that cover your bases right out of the box. Codeigniter is a good choice becase it's easy and fast to set up so you can move on and focus on your game. If however you're just making a simple javascript game with a database backend, it may be overkill to set up an entire MVC framework for it. But, if you need the practice, then what better time to start than now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A framework, particularly one like CI that has so much community support would be a good choice for creating a browser game (obviously depending on the game type) It does really depend on the type of game you want to create but they will all use a database to one degree or another and most frameworks have good DB support to make things easier.

The idea behind frameworks in general is to give you a set of tools to work with and cut down on development time. Why write your own form validation when it's been done tons of times before basically.

MVC itself is just common sense programming really and game or not it's something you should understand and be doing on every project in my opinion.

That being said, even though I work in CI, I have heard some downsides and complaints about it. There are a number of PHP frameworks including but not limited to, Zend, CakePHP, Laravel and Fuel. Check them all out, decide what it is your project is going to need from a framework and base your decision on which framework works the best with your requirements.